# Handler failed to bind to ip:port (my port is open)

Tags: metasploit

I was trying to do some connection testing with my metasploit on external network, but I can not connect to it even though my port is open.

[image: Testing the port]

Testing the port

But when I try to connect to make a connection with my ip and port, but metasploit can not listen to it

```
msfconsole
Metasploit Park, System Security Interface
Version 4.0.5, Alpha E
Ready...
> access security
access: PERMISSION DENIED.
> access security grid
access: PERMISSION DENIED.
> access main security grid
access: PERMISSION DENIED....and...
YOU DIDN'T SAY THE MAGIC WORD!
YOU DIDN'T SAY THE MAGIC WORD!
YOU DIDN'T SAY THE MAGIC WORD!
YOU DIDN'T SAY THE MAGIC WORD!
YOU DIDN'T SAY THE MAGIC WORD!
YOU DIDN'T SAY THE MAGIC WORD!
YOU DIDN'T SAY THE MAGIC WORD!


   =[ metasploit v4.16.58-dev                         ]
+ -- --=[ 1769 exploits - 1006 auxiliary - 307 post       ]
+ -- --=[ 537 payloads - 41 encoders - 10 nops            ]
+ -- --=[ Free Metasploit Pro trial: http://r-7.co/trymsp ]

msf > use exploit/multi/handler
msf exploit(multi/handler) > set lhost (myip)
lhost => 189.25.86.175
msf exploit(multi/handler) > set lport 65100
lport => 65100
msf exploit(multi/handler) > exploit                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
[-] Handler failed to bind to (Myip):65100                                                                                                                 
[*] Started HTTPS reverse handler on https://0.0.0.0:65100
```

network settings:

```
    ➜  ~ ifconfig
    lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 8467  bytes 545281 (532.5 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 8467  bytes 545281 (532.5 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    wlp0s29f7u6: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 2804:d41:17f1:1c00::100  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
    inet6 2804:d41:17f1:1c00:54c1:cfb7:9595:5e09  prefixlen 64  
    scopeid 0x0<global>                                                                           
    inet6 fe80::17b0:c4a5:630a:d1fe  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 24:05:0f:db:d9:7e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 401323  bytes 512654975 (488.9 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 185093  bytes 29521350 (28.1 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

➜  ~ netstat -vantu
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:63342         0.0.0.0:*                       LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9050          0.0.0.0:*                       LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6942          0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.10:44598      198.252.206.25:443          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.10:40790      198.252.206.25:443      ESTABLISHED
tcp       32      0 192.168.1.10:46204      34.226.127.56:443           CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.10:39796      151.101.4.134:443       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.10:49804      192.241.182.146:443     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.10:44032      151.101.193.69:443      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.10:53754      151.101.64.134:443      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.10:57500      23.55.33.17:443         TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.10:39724      151.101.4.134:443       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.10:45734      35.186.213.138:443      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.10:55752      104.25.82.110:443       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.10:36628      37.139.12.161:9001      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.10:39278      104.193.19.59:443       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.10:39280      104.193.19.59:443       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.10:39626      151.101.206.49:443      ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 2804:d41:17f1:1c0:49020 2400:cb00:2048:1::6:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 2804:d41:17f1:1c0:36816 2400:cb00:2048:1::6:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 2804:d41:17f1:1c0:37754 2620:0:861:ed1a::1:443  TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 2804:d41:17f1:1c0:48966 2400:cb00:2048:1::6:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 2804:d41:17f1:1c0:58700 2800:3f0:4003:c00::5228 ESTABLISHED
udp        0      0 192.168.1.10:68         0.0.0.0:*
udp    38400      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*
udp6   71564      0 2804:d41:17f1:1c0:32987 2800:3f0:4004:809:::443     ESTABLISHED
udp6   78116      0 2804:d41:17f1:1c0:53672 2800:3f0:4003:c01:::443 ESTABLISHED
udp6    4544      0 2804:d41:17f1:1c0:35316 2800:3f0:4001:802:::443 ESTABLISHED
udp6    4608      0 fe80::17b0:c4a5:630:546 :::*
udp6    4544      0 2804:d41:17f1:1c0:45648 2800:3f0:4004:809:::443 ESTABLISHED
udp6    4544      0 2804:d41:17f1:1c0:53961 2800:3f0:4001:814:::443 ESTABLISHED
udp6    8128      0 2804:d41:17f1:1c0:60206 2800:3f0:4004:809:::443 ESTABLISHED
udp6    4544      0 2804:d41:17f1:1c0:56309 2800:3f0:4001:815:::443 ESTABLISHED
udp6    9132      0 2804:d41:17f1:1c0:50373 2800:3f0:4001:814:::443 ESTABLISHED
udp6    7304      0 2804:d41:17f1:1c0:58574 2800:3f0:4001:808:::443 ESTABLISHED
udp6    4608      0 :::5353                 :::*
udp6   11592      0 2804:d41:17f1:1c0:36622 2800:3f0:4001:814:::443 ESTABLISHED
```

I already did a search and I did not succeed with any answer that could help me.
I have already changed some of the settings of my router, for example, IP address encapsulation, firewall deactivation, I use the cloudflare dns, I do not know if it has imporáncia, but.

To you that can help me, I will be very grateful

Comment: What research have you done so far?

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of text, instead copy and paste the relevant parts. Also, please describe your network setup and what you tried so far. That might help the people on the network stack exchange. This isn’t a security question and should be migrated.

Comment: I will not answer, as this doesn’t belong here. But it seems like you are NAT‘ed. Did you configure a port forward through your NAT (usually a WiFi router) for that specific port?

Comment: Exactly, I configured my router to receive my localhost to go through this port.